# Trouble using data retrieved with Interface from Activity2 on Activity1 Frament

Tags: java, android, android-activity, interface, fragment

I have an `EditText` on my `Activity2` and want to use it in my `Activity1` `Fragment`.
Using `interfaces` that's what I came up with:

In my `Activity2` I have defined and initializated the `interface`:

```java
private OnEditTextData onEditTextData;

    public interface OnEditTextData{
        void sendEdtData(String str);
    }
```

then in the `onCreate` I call the `interface` method on my `EditText` after Attaching the `interface`:

```java
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private EditText editText;
    private OnEditTextData onEditTextData;

    public interface OnEditTextData{
        void sendEdtData(String str);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        btn_next = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btn_previous = findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);
        btn_previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        .
        .
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        onEditTextData = fragment;

        btn_previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                .
                .
                }
            }
        });

        btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                .
                onEditTextData.sendEdtData(editText.getText().toString());
                .    
                }
            }
        });
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Now in my `Activity1` `Fragment` I implemented the `interface` and since I want to store it with shared preferences...:

```java
public class Fragment extends Fragment implements Activity2.OnEditTextData {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
.
.


    @Override
        public void sendEdtData(String str) {
            SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", 0);
            Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("string", str);
            editor.apply();  
        }

}
```

I tried using `Logs` to check if my string arrived in the `Fragment` and it did. But whenever I use it for anything else, like shared preferences, I get a NullPointer error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`

That happened also when I tried to add the string in a `List`.

Comment: post your Activity2 class plz! :)

Comment: You can't just create a Fragment instance and store it like that, it will eventually crash when the system recreates the Fragment.

Comment: when do you get this error? I mean is when you press the button?

Comment: yes when i press the button.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what do you suggest to do then?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is not with your data passing but it is with way you are using your `android` `component`.

use this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", 0);
```

instead of

```
 SharedPreferences settings =this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", 0);
```

Comment: @JacK'o'Lantern Try this to store your data                                                               SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, name);
        editor.apply();